# Extract all the data from Array and do the sum?

Tags: objective-c

I have added some data into a myMutableArray:

```
- (void)calculate {

    DataObject* pObj = [DataObject objStart:(dataStart) 
                                     objEnd:(dataEnd) 
                                     objDay:(day)];

    [self.myMutableArray addObject:pObj];
}
```

I need to extract then only day (int) and sum all the values.
I was thinking at something like that, but i'm missing how to extract only day ...

```
  for(id *tObj in self.myMutableArray) {
    // day = day + day
 }
```

DataObject is implemented here:

```
   @implementation DataObject

+ (id)objStart:(NSDate*)objStart objEnd:(NSDate*)objEnd objDay:(int)objDay {

DataObject *dataObject = [[self alloc] init];
dataObject.objStart = objStart;
dataObject.objEnd = objEnd;
dataObject.objDay = objDay;
return dataObject;
}
@end
```

Comment: How are objStart objEnd and objDay stored in DataObject?

Comment: They are stored in an NSObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one elegant and really nice solution that cocoa provides with key value coding. You could take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html for more detail.

I dont really understand about your model but I will suppose my own model to provide you the solution, hope you find it interesting.

Say I have a model named **Data** as follows;

```
@interface Data:NSObject
  @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
  @property(nonatomic) int day;
@end
@implementation Data
  @synthesize name, day;
@end
```

Now, in your some classes you create instances of data object and add it to an array.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
Data *data =[ [Data alloc] init];
data.name = @"First Name";
data.day = 10;
[myArray addObject:data];
data = [[Data alloc] init];
data.name = @"Second Name";
data.day = 20;
[myArray addObject:data];
```

Now, with this array you can play kvc game.

```
[myArray valueForKey:@"name"]
```

gives a new array as;

```
(First Name, Last Name)
```

`[myArray valueForKey:@"day"]` gives;

```
(10, 20 )
```

And for sum of all the days, you would just do,

`[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.day"]` and that would provide you with 30.

That's it. Hope I understood your question well. ;)

Comment: I'm going to try it, thanks. btw Data =[ [Data alloc] init]; needs to be execute every time ?

Comment: NSNumber *Tot = [self.myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.day"];
            NSLog(@"day %@", Tot); it gives me null, why ? the data are correctly saved into myArray ... i've checked that using   NSLog(@"Name %@ Day %i", data.name, data.day);

Comment: Are you sure ? Because this is the example I have tested yesterday before commenting here.

Comment: Just wondering: NSNumber * Tot is it correct ? How to extract [myArray valueForKey:@"day"] ? with a NSNumber * days = [myArray valueForKey:@"day"]; ? i need to add a self.myArray as said, that could be the issue ?

Comment: But, if you do [myArray valueForKey:@"day"], it gives you another array that consists day from all the objects not NSNumber object.

Comment: Data * daysTotal = [self.myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.day"];
            NSLog(@"Number of days: %@", daysTotal); how can i have daysTotal in int (like day) ?

Comment: [[self.myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.day"] intValue];

Comment: if i want instead to cycle the day in a loop ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this ? (I have to make a lot of self-assumptions)

```
NSUInteger totalDay;
for(id tObj in self.myMutableArray) {
    // day = day + day
  totalDay+=tObj.objDay;
}
```

Comment: do you mean pObj ? what id stands for ? i've tried that but i receive an error Selector element type '_strong id*' is not a valid object

Comment: i've changed into for(pObj in self.myMutableArray) { totalDay+= pObj.day; } but no values are extracted ...

Comment: in my code *tObj is new object ( a counter ) that traverses for each object of myMutableArray. and from each object tObj, day is retrived. it is something like for(long i=0 i< [myMutableArray count] i++ ) { id newObj=[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]; totalDay+=newObj.day; }

Comment: ehm but how day is retrived ? day in my case is named objDay. i continue to receive that error (sorry i'm a new to Objective c)

Comment: Now the error is gone but i receive a new error in tObj.objDay property 'objDay' not found ...