# Converting data (from a model) in int

Tags: objective-c

I've this model:

> ```
> @interface Data : NSObject
> @property (nonatomic, assign) NSDate *Start;
> @property (nonatomic, assign) NSDate *End;
> @property (nonatomic, assign) int Days;
> @property (nonatomic, assign) double moneyEuro;
> @property (nonatomic, assign) double moneyUsa;
> @end
> ```

a mutable Array:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* myArray;
```

add data into Array:

```
Data *data =[ [Data alloc] init];
data.Start = startTemp;
data.End = endTemp;
data.Days = daysTemp;
data.moneyEuro = moneyEuroTemp;
data.moneyUsa = moneyUsaTemp;
[self.myArray addObject:data];
```

then i want to extract only the int Days and sum them:

```
  Data * daysArr = [self.myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.Days"];
  NSLog(@"days %@", daysArr);
```

BUT daysArr is a NSString ??? NSLogs works properly ...

How to change daysArr into int (as should be cause Days are int) ?

I've tried with:

```
Days = [daysArr intValue];
```

but i receive the error: no visible interface for data declares the selector intValue

Comment: How is `daysArr` of type `NSString`? You declared as type `Data`, which inherits from `NSObject`.

Comment: @yeesterbunny yes, it's a Data and inherits from NSObject: but when i extract it (days) from self.myArray days should't be an int as declared in my model ? I'm a bit confused ... i need the result sum.Days in int ...

Comment: What is the type of `sum`? Is it of type `Data` as well? If so, `sum.Days` is an `int`. The problem is that `daysArr` is not `NSString`. You can do a check `if([daysArr isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){ NSLog(@"It's a NSString!)}` or something like that.

Comment: I check: daysArr it's NOT a string! ehm ... don't know exactly sum.Days ... please see that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586345/extract-all-the-data-from-array-and-do-the-sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Key-Value Coding Programming Guide" states for the "@sum" collection operator:

> The @sum operator returns the sum of the values of the property
>   specified by the key path to the right of the operator. Each number is
>   converted to a double, the sum of the values is computed, and the
>   total is wrapped as an instance of NSNumber and returned.

So the following should work:

```
NSNumber *sumDays = [self.myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.Days"];
int days = [sumDays intValue];
```